# ¿Como eliminar datos de un array ? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Quisiera enviar el objeto y eliminar el mismo existente almacenado en el `array` **Lista** (con los datos iguales `CO_EMPR`, `NU_SECU`).

Adjunto función:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const Lista = [
        { CO_EMPR: 18, NU_SECU: 3 },
        { CO_EMPR: 18, NU_SECU: 5 }
    ] 

    const sp_Fila= { CO_EMPR: 18, NU_SECU: 5 }

    function Items_Migrar_OC(sp_Fila) {

         //  Eliminar registro ya existente en el array
         //  ...

        console.log(Lista);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Debes saber que si deseas eliminar un registro ya existente de tu array primero debes declararlo como una variable no como una constante

Comment: Si colega esa parte ya la tengo, solo que resumí el código para querer ir al grano de lo que deseo desarrollar

Comment: Acabo de revertir la edición que hiciste para que concuerde la pregunta y mi respuesta, por favor amigo crea una nueva pregunta con el nuevo problema y te ayudaremos :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el método [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) para filtrar los valores de tu `array` y generar uno nuevo dependiendo las condiciones que añadas en la función del filtro:

```js
var Lista = [
  { CO_EMPR: 18, NU_SECU: 3 },
  { CO_EMPR: 18, NU_SECU: 5 }
] 

const sp_Fila= { CO_EMPR: 18, NU_SECU: 5 }

function Items_Migrar_OC(sp_Fila) {
  Lista = Lista.filter(function(elemento){
    return elemento.CO_EMPR != sp_Fila.CO_EMPR || elemento.NU_SECU != sp_Fila.NU_SECU
  });
  
  console.log(Lista);
}

Items_Migrar_OC(sp_Fila);
```

Básicamente lo que hacemos en el `filter` es recorrer el `array` de objetos, si alguno de los valores de las dos propiedades del objeto en iteración son diferentes a los valores de las propiedades del objeto que pasas como parámetro entonces se entiende que no son los mismos objetos por lo cual el resultado de la condición sería un `true` y esto permitiría conservar el objeto actual.

Comment: Hola; lo realizaré en base a tu respuesta, una consulta y si tengo 100 items por ejemplo esto no afecta en la calidad de respuesta del código utilizando filter ?

Comment: Filter es el método que sirve para solucionar este tipo de problemas, no debería afectar tu rendimiento, yo lo he usado para cantidad de datos exagerada y nunca me ha afectado

Comment: Colega, tengo un inconveniente aplicando la respuesta brindada al momento de validar el registro para eliminar sucede lo siguiente: 1. ingreso dos filas 2. elimino una 3. ingreso una fila de datos y al contar el length el registro eliminado con filter lo deja como "vacío" (empty) cuando no debería considerar contar este valor que sería lo correcto. Estoy modificando la pregunta con el ejemplo completo e imagen.

Comment: @RobinsonAscencioPeña no entendí el problema pero espera, las preguntas no deben editarse conforme encuentras mas problemas, debes de crear otra pregunta con el nuevo problema y dar por finalizada esta

Comment: De acuerdo, Gracias.

Comment: Buenas, estuve implementando el ejemplo pero cuando intento borrar elementos me devuelve indefinido dentro del array y lo considera en el length. Te adjunto el link del código implementado.  https://playcode.io/398069?tabs=script.js,preview,console
Gracias

Comment: @RobinsonAscencioPeña haz la pregunta por favor para poderte ayudar con tu problema

Comment: la pregunta está en el siguiente link: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/281851/eliminar-valores-de-un-array-javascript  Gracias