# Eliminar valores de un array

Tags: javascript

Estuve investigando poco a poco y obtuve el siguiente script que realiza lo siguiente:

1. Al recibir el valor Item_Seleccionado == 1 insertado los datos almacenados en el array.
2. Al recibir el valor 2 debería eliminarme los datos de valor fila y eliminarlos en el array, al realizar este proceso los elimina pero deja como indefinido o empty y este valor lo considera en el length.

¿Cúal sería la forma correcta de eliminar los elementos sin que este lo deje indefinido y pueda realizar correctamente el length?

[image]

Envío el link de pruebas en consola sobre este ejemplo:  https://playcode.io/398069?tabs=script.js,preview,console

```
 var Lista = [];
        var Fila_r = {};
        let count = 0;

        function Items_Migrar_OC(CO_EMPR, TI_REQI, NU_REQI, NU_SECU, CO_ITEM, CA_SOLI, CA_ATEN, CA_PEND, Item_Seleccionado) {
            //alert(Item_Seleccionado);

            var duplicado = false;

            Fila_r = { CO_EMPR, TI_REQI, NU_REQI, NU_SECU, CO_ITEM, CA_SOLI, CA_ATEN, CA_PEND }

            if (Item_Seleccionado == "1")
             {

                //Si no es vacío verifica con función duplicado
                if (Lista != null){
                    duplicado = validateUnique(Fila_r)
                    //alert(duplicado);
                }

                // Si no existe ingresa datos al array
                if (duplicado == false) {
                    Lista[count] = Fila_r
                    count++;
                }
            }
            else {
                Lista = Lista.filter(function (elemento) {
                    return elemento.NU_SECU != Fila_r.NU_SECU
                });
            }

            console.log(Lista);
        }

        function validateUnique(myObject) {
            return !!Lista.find(i => i.NU_SECU === myObject.NU_SECU)
        }

//Empezamos con todo simulamos que insera un dato
Items_Migrar_OC(1,2,3,1,5,6,7,8,"1");
Items_Migrar_OC(2,2,3,2,5,6,7,8,"1");
Items_Migrar_OC(3,2,3,3,5,6,7,8,"1");
//hasta aqui hay 3
console.log(Lista.length)
//mandamos para remover uno
Items_Migrar_OC(3,2,3,3,5,6,7,8,"0");
//hasta aqui hay 2
console.log(Lista.length)
//agregamos 1 nuevamente
Items_Migrar_OC(3,2,3,3,5,6,7,8,"1");
//hasta aqui hay 3 nuevamente pero nos da resultado 4
console.log(Lista.length)
//Nos devuelve:
console.log(Lista);
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Revisa esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/282723/822

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa con tu código es lo siguiente:

- Cuando añades un elemento en tu `array` estás sumando una unidad a una variable contador, ej: (1,2,3)
- Esta variable contador sirve para generar los índices nuevos del `array`.
- Cuando eliminas un elemento y agregas uno nuevo el contador sigue aumentando su valor desde el valor anterior, ej (1,2,3,4), pero en el `array` el índice anterior ya no existe por lo cual se genera el nuevo índice dejando el anterior vacío.

La solución a esto es restar una unidad a la variable contador al momento de eliminar un elemento del `array`.

```js
var Lista = [];
var Fila_r = {};
let count = 0;

function Items_Migrar_OC(CO_EMPR, TI_REQI, NU_REQI, NU_SECU, CO_ITEM, CA_SOLI, CA_ATEN, CA_PEND, Item_Seleccionado) {
    //alert(Item_Seleccionado);

    var duplicado = false;

    Fila_r = { CO_EMPR, TI_REQI, NU_REQI, NU_SECU, CO_ITEM, CA_SOLI, CA_ATEN, CA_PEND }

    if (Item_Seleccionado == "1")
     {

        //Si no es vacío verifica con función duplicado
        if (Lista != null){
            duplicado = validateUnique(Fila_r)
            //alert(duplicado);
        }

        // Si no existe ingresa datos al array
        if (duplicado == false) {
            Lista[count] = Fila_r
            count++;
        }
    }
    else {
        Lista = Lista.filter(function (elemento) {
            return elemento.NU_SECU != Fila_r.NU_SECU
        });
        
        count--;
    }

    console.log(Lista);
}

function validateUnique(myObject) {
    return !!Lista.find(i => i.NU_SECU === myObject.NU_SECU)
}

//Empezamos con todo simulamos que insera un dato
Items_Migrar_OC(1,2,3,1,5,6,7,8,"1");
Items_Migrar_OC(2,2,3,2,5,6,7,8,"1");
Items_Migrar_OC(3,2,3,3,5,6,7,8,"1");
//hasta aqui hay 3
console.log(Lista.length)
//mandamos para remover uno
Items_Migrar_OC(3,2,3,3,5,6,7,8,"0");
//hasta aqui hay 2
console.log(Lista.length)
//agregamos 1 nuevamente
Items_Migrar_OC(3,2,3,3,5,6,7,8,"1");
//hasta aqui hay 3 nuevamente pero nos da resultado 4
console.log(Lista.length)
//Nos devuelve:
console.log(Lista);
```

Otra solución es utilizar el método `.push()` para agregar un valor al final del `array`, así ni siquiera necesitarías el uso de la variable `count`.

```js
var Lista = [];
var Fila_r = {};

function Items_Migrar_OC(CO_EMPR, TI_REQI, NU_REQI, NU_SECU, CO_ITEM, CA_SOLI, CA_ATEN, CA_PEND, Item_Seleccionado) {
    //alert(Item_Seleccionado);

    var duplicado = false;

    Fila_r = { CO_EMPR, TI_REQI, NU_REQI, NU_SECU, CO_ITEM, CA_SOLI, CA_ATEN, CA_PEND }

    if (Item_Seleccionado == "1")
     {

        //Si no es vacío verifica con función duplicado
        if (Lista != null){
            duplicado = validateUnique(Fila_r)
            //alert(duplicado);
        }

        // Si no existe ingresa datos al array
        if (duplicado == false) {
            Lista.push(Fila_r)
        }
    }
    else {
        Lista = Lista.filter(function (elemento) {
            return elemento.NU_SECU != Fila_r.NU_SECU
        });
    }

    console.log(Lista);
}

function validateUnique(myObject) {
    return !!Lista.find(i => i.NU_SECU === myObject.NU_SECU)
}

//Empezamos con todo simulamos que insera un dato
Items_Migrar_OC(1,2,3,1,5,6,7,8,"1");
Items_Migrar_OC(2,2,3,2,5,6,7,8,"1");
Items_Migrar_OC(3,2,3,3,5,6,7,8,"1");
//hasta aqui hay 3
console.log(Lista.length)
//mandamos para remover uno
Items_Migrar_OC(3,2,3,3,5,6,7,8,"0");
//hasta aqui hay 2
console.log(Lista.length)
//agregamos 1 nuevamente
Items_Migrar_OC(3,2,3,3,5,6,7,8,"1");
//hasta aqui hay 3 nuevamente pero nos da resultado 4
console.log(Lista.length)
//Nos devuelve:
console.log(Lista);
```

Comment: Perfectamente explicado, intente con push y me funciona muy bien. Gracias por el aporte.