# Desde Json convertir Lista Generica a DataSet en C#

Tags: c#, json, reflection

Hace un momento vi una pregunta muy interesante sobre cómo generar un **DataSet** en base a una lista genérica que viene desde un **JSON**, como la pregunta fue eliminada y alcancé a copiar la estructura del **JSON**, aquí va una colaboración con la comunidad:

```
[
  {
    "CO_EMPR": "18",
    "TI_REQI": "RAL",
    "NU_REQI": "0001-0000000049",
    "SECUENCIA": "4",
    "CODIGO_ITEM": "600101008",
    "CANTIDAD_SOLICITADA": "5"
  },
  {
    "CO_EMPR": "18",
    "TI_REQI": "RAL",
    "NU_REQI": "0001-0000000049",
    "SECUENCIA": "5",
    "CODIGO_ITEM": "600401036",
    "CANTIDAD_SOLICITADA": "5"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar, cuando se trabaja con conversiones de ese tipo de estructuras, se necesita hacer un "parsing" del JSON a una clase o una lista de clases. Segundo, recién cuando se tiene el JSON "parseado" con una clase o lista, se procede a hacer la transformación.

La pregunta me llamó mucho la atención, puesto que se juega con Generics y Reflection para alcanzar la funcionalidad solicitada.

Como desconocía los valores del tipo de los datos, coloqué una clase sencilla (ElementoIndividual) con propiedades de puros strings y una clase adicional generada por cortesía de [Mockaroo](https://mockaroo.com/).

Sin más detalles qué agregar, al código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var json = @"[{""CO_EMPR"":""18"",""TI_REQI"":""RAL"",""NU_REQI"":""0001-0000000049"",""SECUENCIA"":""4"",""CODIGO_ITEM"":""600101008"",""CANTIDAD_SOLICITADA"":""5""},{""CO_EMPR"":""18"",""TI_REQI"":""RAL"",""NU_REQI"":""0001-0000000049"",""SECUENCIA"":""5"",""CODIGO_ITEM"":""600401036"",""CANTIDAD_SOLICITADA"":""5""}]";

            List<ElementoIndividual> miListaGenerica = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ElementoIndividual>>(json);
            var resultadoDataSet = CrearDataSet(miListaGenerica);

            Console.WriteLine(resultadoDataSet.GetXml());

            var json2 = @"[{ ""id"":1,""first_name"":""Sharleen"",""last_name"":""Carbry"",""email"":""scarbry0@reddit.com"",""phone"":""286-408-8677"",""random"":3},{ ""id"":2,""first_name"":""Holli"",""last_name"":""Fearns"",""email"":""hfearns1@china.com.cn"",""phone"":""448-956-6372"",""random"":22},{ ""id"":3,""first_name"":""Marabel"",""last_name"":""Millichip"",""email"":""mmillichip2@w3.org"",""phone"":""458-601-0766"",""random"":80}]";

            List<Mockaroo> miListaGenerica2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Mockaroo>>(json2);
            var resultado2 = CrearDataSet(miListaGenerica2);
            Console.WriteLine(resultado2.GetXml());

            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public static DataSet CrearDataSet<T>(this IList<T> list)
        {
            Type elementType = typeof(T);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            ds.Tables.Add(t);

            //Agregar una columna a la tabla para cada propiedad pública en T
            foreach (var propInfo in elementType.GetProperties())
            {
                //ColType = Column Type = Tipo de dato que hay en la columna
                Type ColType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propInfo.PropertyType) ?? propInfo.PropertyType;

                t.Columns.Add(propInfo.Name, ColType);
            }

            //Recorrer cada propiedad en T y añadir cada valor a la tabla
            foreach (T item in list)
            {
                DataRow row = t.NewRow();

                foreach (var propInfo in elementType.GetProperties())
                {
                    row[propInfo.Name] = propInfo.GetValue(item, null) ?? DBNull.Value;
                }

                t.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            return ds;
        }
    }


    public class ElementoIndividual
    {
        public string CO_EMPR { get; set; }
        public string TI_REQI { get; set; }
        public string NU_REQI { get; set; }
        public string SECUENCIA { get; set; }
        public string CODIGO_ITEM { get; set; }
        public string CANTIDAD_SOLICITADA { get; set; }
    }

    public class Mockaroo
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public int random { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Y aqui tenemos lo generado por el GetXML()

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <CO_EMPR>18</CO_EMPR>
    <TI_REQI>RAL</TI_REQI>
    <NU_REQI>0001-0000000049</NU_REQI>
    <SECUENCIA>4</SECUENCIA>
    <CODIGO_ITEM>600101008</CODIGO_ITEM>
    <CANTIDAD_SOLICITADA>5</CANTIDAD_SOLICITADA>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <CO_EMPR>18</CO_EMPR>
    <TI_REQI>RAL</TI_REQI>
    <NU_REQI>0001-0000000049</NU_REQI>
    <SECUENCIA>5</SECUENCIA>
    <CODIGO_ITEM>600401036</CODIGO_ITEM>
    <CANTIDAD_SOLICITADA>5</CANTIDAD_SOLICITADA>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <id>1</id>
    <first_name>Sharleen</first_name>
    <last_name>Carbry</last_name>
    <email>scarbry0@reddit.com</email>
    <phone>286-408-8677</phone>
    <random>3</random>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <id>2</id>
    <first_name>Holli</first_name>
    <last_name>Fearns</last_name>
    <email>hfearns1@china.com.cn</email>
    <phone>448-956-6372</phone>
    <random>22</random>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <id>3</id>
    <first_name>Marabel</first_name>
    <last_name>Millichip</last_name>
    <email>mmillichip2@w3.org</email>
    <phone>458-601-0766</phone>
    <random>80</random>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: En cuanto al _"parsing" del JSON a una clase_, visual studio puede hacer esto automáticamente (creo que a partir de 2012). Simplemente, hay que copiar el json y en el visual studio ir a _Editar_ / _Pegado especial_ / _Pegar JSON como clases_